# How remove title page's set date

Tags: beamer, titles, datetime

how to delete the surrounded date without deleting the footer's date?

[image]

I've tried `\date{}`, but this would remove the footer's date too.

Comment: @Sigur, that've worked, thank you. Do you want to put it as an answer or do I close the topic?

Comment: Thanx, to remove date from title \date{} worked perfectly well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the footer makes use of the shorter version of the date you can use an option to pass it to the footer.

```
 \date[\today]{}
```

Then the empty mandatory argument is used for the title page and the optional argument is used for headers/footers.

The same applies to `\title[]{}`, `\author[]{}`, `\institution[]{}` and so on.